# NamedQuery selectively define attributes

Tags: jpa, named-query, toplink

I have namedQuery in Entity class defined as

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Emp.findAll", 
query = " select new test.entity.Emp(o.empNo, o.salary, o.project) from Emp o ")
```

Constructor

```
public Emp(String empNo, String salary, Project project) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.salary=  salary;
        this.project = project;
        }
```

and generated SQL is

```
SELECT t0.emp_no, t0.salary, t1.project_id, t1.project_name, t1.project_desc
FROM EMP t0, PROJECTS t1 WHERE (t1.project_id (+) = t0.project_id)
```

In namedQuery how do I selectively declare projectId and projectName instead of all attributes from Project class? I wouldn't like to display all attributes of Project class in namedQuery.

How can I achieve this?

Update 1

```
public Emp(String empNo, String salary, Long projectId, String projectName) {
        Project pr = new Project();
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.salary=  salary;
        pr.setProjectId = projectId;
        pr.setProjectName = projectName;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (and update the constructor accordingly)

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Emp.findAll", 
query = " select new test.entity.Emp(o.empNo, o.salary, p.projectId, p.projectName) from Emp o inner join o.project p ")
```

Constructor will be something like this

```
public Emp(String empNo, String salary, Long projectId, String projectName) {
    this.empNo = empNo;
    this.salary=  salary;
    Project pr = new Project();
    pr.setProjectId(projectId);
    pr.setProjectName(projectName);

    this.project = pr;
}
```

Comment: I do not have `projectId` defined in Emp class, only `Project` class.

Comment: I have modified constructor as `this.project.setProjectId(projectId);` However I am getting `Exception Description: An Exception was thrown while executing a ReportQuery with a constructor expression: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Query: ReportQuery(test.entity.Emp)`

Comment: If you can't change that, then instantiate `new Project()` in the constructor, and set od and name on it.

Comment: I have modified constructor and included in my question as Update 1. But when I execute, I am getting null for `project`

Comment: You are missing `this.project = pr;`, I've updated my answer.